# Unwanted newline after header in Markdown

Tags: text, formatting, markdown

I am adding a ## (h2) header in Markdown and I want the following line to be directly under the header but there is an additional blank line between the Header and Line under.

Example (how it looks now):

> ## Header
>
> line after with a blank space under

I dont want that line after the Header line....

Answer (score 5):

There is no "blank line". It's simply that the header has a bottom margin which makes it appear that a blank line exists. If you want no extra whitespace between the header and the line following it, just define some CSS which removes any margin:

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Note that the above rule applies only to `<h2>` headers. For all headers you can do:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the next line being bold, you can use `<br>` and `<sup>` in order to achieve this. Technically, the second line will still be h2, it'll just appear smaller because of `<sup>`.

```
## Header<br><sup>Line under header</sup>
```

**Result:**

### Header
<sup>Line under header</sup>